# Some error with jQuery, can't hide an element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

A  [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js)  problem

I want to make an element hide instantly with a function. Here's mine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>A test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <h1 id="heading">This will hide instantly after 3 seconds.</h1>
  <script>
    var hide = function (time) {
      $("#heading").fadeOut(time);
    };
    setTimeout(hide(0), 3000);
  </script>
</body>
<html>
```

But, the heading won't show at the start.
If this doesn't work for you, try wait for 4 seconds and reload the page.

**NOTE: I'm using TextEdit and my browser is Google Chrome.**

However, this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>A test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <h1 id="heading">This will hide instantly after 3 seconds.</h1>
  <script>
    var hide = function () {
      $("#heading").fadeOut(0);
    };
    setTimeout(hide, 3000);
  </script>
</body>
<html>
```

I just want to make a function that can hold all the numbers, so I only need to create function instead of millions.

How could I change the code a little to make the first code work?

Comment: setTimeout expects a function as the first argument, you are passing the result of calling the function in the first example ... you could do `setTimeout(()=>hide(0), 3000);`

Comment: In the first snippet you are passing the function call result to setTimeout, thats why its not working, you should pass a function, not a function call.

Comment: Thank you. I guess maybe the computer is confused that the time is 0 mini seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the function parameter into the third argument so please change the set timeout code with this setTimeout(hide, 3000, 0);

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>A test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <h1 id="heading">This will hide instantly after 3 seconds.</h1>
  <script>
    var hide = function () {
      $("#heading").fadeOut(arguments[0]);
    };
    setTimeout(hide, 3000, 0);
  </script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Please check the syntax of this function from this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: Do you have checked this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var hide = function (time) {
      console.log(time);
      $("#heading").fadeOut(time);
    };
    setTimeout(()=>hide(10), 3000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>A test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <h1 id="heading">This will hide instantly after 3 seconds.</h1>
</body>
<html>
```

Try this one.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to test it.